# Согласно какому правилу сортируется SortedMap?

Tags: java

Добавляю в `TreeMap`, объявленный как `SortedMap`, значения в одном порядке, но выводя на консоль увидел, что хранит он их в другом порядке.

Согласно какому правилу он их сортирует после добавления?

Как задать своё правило сортировки?

```
SortedMap<String, Element> SortedSubMap = new TreeMap<String,Element>();
for(Element element : result) { // записываю в одном порядке
    SortedSubMap.put(dataCollections.toString(element.getBirthDate()), element);
}
for(Element element : SortedSubMap.values()) { // выводит в другом
    System.out.println(dateCollections.toString(element.getBirthDate()));
}
```

Comment: ну раз Sorted, то в порядке возрастания ключа. (Ключ - String).

Comment: А как задать свой порядок? Для ключа?

Comment: переопредели компаратор.

Comment: В документации все написано: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

Answer (score 0):

Сортирует по ключу в натуральном порядке (ключ д.б. Comparable). Для кастомного порядка сортировки в конструктор реализации можно передать Comparator:

```
new TreeMap<>(yourComparator);
```